# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ask for action when I press ACPI Power button/key on VirtualBox (now immediately shutdowns)?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, 18.04, systemd, acpi

I rewrite this question to be clear. I have problems only on VirtualBox.

## 1. Physical hardware

If press Power Button on physical hardware:

- on console ttys system shutdowns
- on the GDM system goes to sleep (suspends)
- in GNOME session it goes to suspend

If I manually run `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action interactive` GNOME asks me what to do.

> Power Off
> The system will power off automatically in 60 seconds
> Cancel | Restart | Power Off
> [image: Confirmation dialog on physical hardware]

It is expected behavior.
But currently there is no such option in GUI (`gnome-control-center power`), request for enhancement was filed as [bug 1769614](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1769614) :

[image: gnome-control-center power on physical hardware]

## 2. VirtualBox guest

### 2.1. Problem

I have ordinary Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed as **VirtualBox guest ( ! ! ! )**.

When I press <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (or *Machine->ACPI Shutdown*) to initiate reaction on ACPI Power Button press it shutdowns immediately.

I expect that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with default desktop would ask me about action on pressing power button as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS do:

[image: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS asks for action after pressing power button]

or as Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS do:

[image: Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS asks for action after pressing power button]

### 2.2. Analysis

I did some investigations with no positive results.

System journal reports that `systemd-logind` may handle ACPI Power key.

Its settings are default:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep -i power
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

I have set GNOME to use *interactive* reaction on Power button:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i power | grep -i button
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'interactive'
```

Once more interesting thing that I do not have *When the Power Button is pressed* in VM (it is [bug 1769623](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1769623)):

[image: gnome-control-center power in VM]

Setting `HandlePowerKey=ignore` in */etc/systemd/logind.conf* does not help:

```
sudo sed -i "s/#HandlePowerKey=poweroff/HandlePowerKey=ignore/" /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

so I set it back

```
sudo sed -i "s/HandlePowerKey=ignore/#HandlePowerKey=poweroff/" /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

So I reported [bug 1769372 to LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1769372).

Note: in terminal session aka `multi-user.target` (`systemctl isolate multi-user.target`) all variables from */etc/systemd/logind.conf* are sourced normally. So the problem is with GNOME session (`systemctl isolate graphical.target`) in `gnome-settings-daemon` or something other.

## Question

**How to stop such behavior in VM?

Does anyone have the same problem in VM or real hardware?**

Comment: Just tested on May 6 2018 18.04 upgrade and the power off menu appears for about 1 second before shutting down Unity. Will grep 18.04 gsetring differences to 16.04 when I get home later.

Comment: As independent test I tried ArchLinux with latest GNOME and MATE on VirtualBox: after `<RightCtrl+H>` MATE asks, GNOME shutdowns quietly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a fresh upgrade on May 6, 2018 on Ubuntu 16.04 clone to 18.04 and confirmed when pressing the power button the "old" menu appears for a split second and then the machine suspends.

I checked `gsettings` using:

```
gsettings list-recursively | sed 's/  */\n/;s/  */\n/;s/\&/\&amp;/g' | yad --list --title "gsettings" --item-seperator='\n' --width=1800 --height=800 --wrap-width=600 --column=Group --column=Key --column=Setting --no-markup
```

sorted by "key" and scrolled down to "power". You can confirm your settings with:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action
'interactive'
```

Checking with Ubuntu 16.04 set it the same using:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action suspend
```

Double check the settings:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action
'suspend'
```

You don't need to reboot. Simply press the power button and now the menu will come up and stay where you can select from:

[image: Ubuntu Power Button.gif]

I borrowed this `.gif` from another answer I wrote. It shows how the lock screen option was missing and how to bring it back.

Comment: It is OK on physical hardware, but does not work on VirtualBox (5.1 in my case).