# Where is the power off button in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?

Tags: shutdown, 18.04

Just updated from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. New version of Ubuntu doesn't contain any power off button in both lockscreen and homescreen, obviously. Adding some gnome extensions couldn't help me either.

Please help me out.
Thank you, guys.

Comment: Maybe your Alt key is stuck.  When on, that changes the power-off to a "pause".  Click and Hold also changes the power-off to pause, but I don't see how that could be a stuck button.

Comment: On your sign in, click the gear and pick the fifth desktop called **Unity**

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the top right corner, it will show you a drop-down menu.

In that place, the power button [image: power button] is placed.

- on login screen

  [image: Power button location in greeter]
- in desktop session

  [image: Power button location in session]

It will open the menu with *Cancel*, *Restart* and *Power Off*:

[image: menu]

Comment: There's no option for shutdown tho.

Comment: I would edit this for you but I honestly don't know what 'despegable' is supposed to mean.

Comment: I have only setting button, restart-shape button, Lock button and Pause button instead of those screws button,  Lock button and Power off button.

Answer (score 2):

I currently don't have 18.04 installed, but if you can't find it you can always use the terminal and type the command:

```
sudo shutdown -h 0
```

This is how I typically shutdown my laptop.

Comment: I just found out shut down icon when I search it. Don't know yet it works or not. But there's no button in menu from the right corner.

Answer (score 2):

### Sign In with Unity

To get the familiar interface to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you need to sign in using the **Unity** interface. Do this right on the Sign In screen:

[image: Ubuntu 18 five desktops.jpg]

click the "gear" to select the Unity Desktop Environment (DE).

### Familiar look and feel

Now you will see the familiar "gear" on the top right of your screen where you can select "Lock Screen", "Log Out", "Suspend" and "Shutdown". If you press the power button you'll get your regular selector:

[image: Ubuntu Power Button]

This video also shows how to activate the lock screen option which is disabled for some users.

Also of interest is some users are not getting a chance to select an action because system shuts down immediately: [How to make Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ask for action when I press ACPI Power button/key on VirtualBox (now immediately shutdowns)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032461/how-to-make-ubuntu-18-04-lts-ask-for-action-when-i-press-acpi-power-button-key-o/1032948#1032948)

Comment: The gear and choices under it may not be present at login if  Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for the tip. I haven't got around to installing nVidia drivers on 18.04 testing yet but I'll check that out down the road.