# Can't find lock computer option in ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, lock-screen

When I click ctrl+alt+del I wan to lock my computer (not log off). I can not find the `lock` option, only `log out` and it says

> [user] will be logged out automatically in 60 seconds

How to enable lock screen in ubuntu 18 and disable auto log out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default keyboard shortcut in ubuntu 18 :

- Lock screen is `Super + L`
- Log out is `Ctrl + Alt + Delete`

If you want to change it, you can change it in Setting > Devices > Keyboard > System

Comment: What is `Super`? Sorry, I never heard about this button?

Comment: key next to `Alt` key, which has Windows logo on it, sir

Answer (score 4):

As per this answer: [Where is the power off button in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034196/where-is-the-power-off-button-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1034271#1034271) try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: The answer you linked was definitely unrelated; however, this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Default keyboard shortcut in Xubuntu 18 seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for those using this flavor