# Suspend Button in interactive power button menu

Tags: gnome

Is there a way/extension to add a suspend entry (besides the Cancel, Restart and Power Off buttons) to the interactive menu when the physical power button is pressed in gnome?

Edit: I am not looking for the suspend button in the menu in the top right corner where suspend can be accessed using the Alt button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the suspend/hibernate button in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967205/where-is-the-suspend-hibernate-button-in-gnome-shell)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think that that is what I am looking for. The other question is looking for a suspend button in the top right menu but I am looking for a possibility to add a suspend filed to the interactive menu when the physical power button is pressed.

Comment: You mean like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034196/where-is-the-power-off-button-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts second answer

Comment: Exactly!
In that menu (last picture in the second answer) I would like to add a "Suspend" option.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an extension that does exactly what you want: [Suspend Button by laser_b](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/), it appears to have problems with current versions of Ubuntu 18.04.

Another option is using **Unity** instead of **Gnome**: [Where is the power off button in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034271/307523)

---

Your best bet is to change Gnome's configuration of what happens when you press the power button. Rather than the "Power Off" it can be changed to "Suspend". After the change, if you want to "Power Off" then hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for Power off option when Power Button is pressed.

[image: Gnome Power Settings]

Notice the bottom right corner where you select "Suspend".

<sub>Image and Concept Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/968628/307523</sub>

Comment: Actually the extension doesn't exactly offer what OP is looking for. The extension just adds one suspend button in system menu, whereas OP is looking for a way to add the suspend option to the pop-up dialogue which appears once you press the power button.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for clarification. Can you confirm the extension is broken for up-to-date installations? When researching the answer wasn't clear.

Comment: Works fine with my installation of Bionic out of the box.

Comment: @pomsky That's good to know. If you post an answer to this question please ping me so I can delete my answer.